# Solution of differential equation $(4+t^2)y'(t)+2ty(t)=4t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this differential equation
$$(4+t^2)y'(t)+2ty(t)=4t$$
But I can't find the correct solution.
Can I have some advices, please?

Comment: You can get the same solution easier, if you note that $(4+t^2)'=2t$, then equation is $vy'+v'y=4t$ with $v=4+t^2$. $vy'+v'y=(vy)'$

Answer (score 1):

$$(4+t^2)y'(t)+2ty(t)=4t\\
(4+t^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{dt}}+2ty=4t\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{4 - 2 y} = \frac{t}{4 + t^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{4 - 2 y} = \int\frac{t}{4 + t^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2-y)+C_1=\frac{1}{2}\ln(t^2+4)+C_2\\
y(t) = \frac{2 t^2+c_3}{t^2 + 4}
$$